# how to Automatic insert record in the secondary table?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

hi guys this is my tables structure :

reqest and Request_state :

[image]

I want to automatically create a record in Request_STATE Table when a record is added to Request Table
Request_state stores the status information of Request Table
What method do you suggest?
Does it make sense to create an event? Without using a trigger

Comment: yes, event is a good choice

Comment: Did my anser help your problem? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can quite easily do it with the inbuilt Model event in `Laravel`, which can be subscribed on th model `boot()` method. The created is triggered afted saving and there is multiple events you can subscribe to see them [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events).

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RequestState extends Model {
    table = 'request_state';

    public function request()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Request::class);
    }
}

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Request extends Model {
    public static function boot() {
        static::created(function ($request) {
            $requestState = new RequestState([
                // your data
            ]); 
            $requestState->request->associate($request);
            $requestState->save();
        });
    }
}
```

This will only trigger with `Laravel` models, but when you do it will create a new Request with an state.

```
Request::create([]);
```

An alternative approach using an `Listener` can obtain the same, but move the logic out of the model. This is the easy straight forward solution and it is a little easier to maintain, as you do not scour the logic in listeners.

Comment: If it helped please accept it as an answer to the left of the question :)